# How to scan, find and connect to an open wifi AP programatically?

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-wifi, access-point

I am developing an application which should automarically and periodically enable wifi, scan for networks, filter out networks that are open (no pass needed), create a wifiConfiguration object and use it to connect to that network.

I read the wifiConfiguration API on android developers. And based on it I have written a sample of code which does enable the wifi, scans for networks and saves the result in a list which looks like that:

```
11-25 16:05:44.191: I/WIFISCAN(12955): List of networks: [SSID: airlive_w, BSSID: 00:4f:62:2c:96:18, capabilities: [WPA-PSK-CCMP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS], level: -71, frequency: 2432, SSID: Mikynet, BSSID: 00:1e:2a:ed:62:4e, capabilities: [WPA2-PSK-CCMP], level: -72, frequency: 2427, SSID: TP-LINK_Vectra, BSSID: 74:ea:3a:ab:eb:b0, capabilities: [WPA2-PSK-TKIP+CCMP][WPS], level: -73, frequency: 2462, SSID: Nasza Siec- ryby, BSSID: d8:5d:4c:df:60:74, capabilities: [WPA2-PSK-TKIP+CCMP-preauth], level: -88, frequency: 2437, SSID: lanzarote, BSSID: 00:27:19:f7:05:9c, capabilities: [WPA-PSK-TKIP+CCMP][WPA2-PSK-TKIP+CCMP-preauth], level: -89, frequency: 2437, SSID: Alicja, BSSID: 94:44:52:a7:17:02, capabilities: [WPA-PSK-CCMP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS], level: -89, frequency: 2442, SSID: orangebox, BSSID: 00:1f:f3:f8:ea:0f, capabilities: [WPA2-PSK-CCMP], level: -89, frequency: 2462]
```

**Having that result how am I going to know which of them is open (pass free)?
And how do I create the wifiConfiguration for an open one?**

Here is a sample wifiConfiguration for a WPA-PSK:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
// This is must be quoted according to the documentation 
// http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html#SSID
wc.SSID = "\"SSIDName\"";
wc.preSharedKey  = "\"password\"";
wc.hiddenSSID = true;
wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;        
wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
int res = wifi.addNetwork(wc);
Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res );
boolean b = wifi.enableNetwork(res, true);        
Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + b );
```

Any guidance will be highly apreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, you might have to try adding an open configuration to the Wifi service. If adding an open network fails, it probably requires some kind of auth protocol.

```
WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
wc.SSID = "some ssid from the list";
wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
wc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);

WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
int networkId = wifi.addNetwork(wc);
if (networkId == -1) {
    // probably not open
} else {
    // likely open
}
```

You could also use this in conjunction with the `getConfiguredNetworks` method to see if any nearby networks a) have been previously connected to and b) are open.

Comment: This example for me return "likely open" for open and networks with password.